# Can you compile a fully self-submitting Spark job as a assembly

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I have access to a large multi-tenant YARN cluster with only Spark 1.6 available (on both the cluster itself and the head servers from which jobs much be launched).

I'd like to run a Spark 2 job (ideally the latest release from a few days ago) on that cluster, and build a deb/rpm package for the job.

Writing the job itself is straight forward, I can build the job as an assembly with all the Spark 2 assemblies compiled in.

However that leaves the problem of launching the job with spark-submit, which I don't have on the head nodes. If this was a simply hacky one-time thing I'd just unroll a tarball of the whole of Spark 2 onto the head nodes and try to launch with that. But in this case that is probably not possible.

I'd like to run the job as a plain Java job with whatever environment variables are needed, and have the main() function for my plain Java application bootstrap the submission of the Spark job

Is there a way to build a Spark job such that it is "self-submitting" and compiles in the additional spark-submit code?